# Pass through Magento Purchase Order number to Shipworks ; then add to Fedex Reference field

Tags: api, magento, fedex, purchase-order

I use Shipworks 3 with Magento 1.5.1 and would like to pass the Purchase order NUMBER through.  Right now the Payment Type comes through but I need the PO number so it can go on/print on the Packaking slip, invoice, AND Shipping label.

Here's a snippet from the shipworks.php.  I'm guessing I just have to add to this section but not sure what to add.

Thank you for any help.

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();

            // CC info
            if ($secure)
            {
                      $cc_num = $payment->getCcNumber();
            }
            else
            {
                      $cc_num = $payment->getCcLast4();
                      if (!empty($cc_num))
                      {
                                 $cc_num = '************'.$payment->getCcLast4();
                      }
            }
            $cc_year = sprintf('%02u%s', $payment->getCcExpMonth(), substr($payment->getCcExpYear(), 2)); 


        writeStartTag("Payment");
        writeElement("Method", Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($payment->getMethod())->getTitle());

        writeStartTag("CreditCard");
        writeElement("Type", $payment->getCcType());
        writeElement("Owner", $payment->getCcOwner());
        writeElement("Number", $cc_num);
        writeElement("Expires", $cc_year);
        writeCloseTag("CreditCard");

        writeCloseTag("Payment");
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the following to get my po number to show up in the notes. This is what I used. hope it helps.

```
// CC info
if ($secure)
{
    $cc_num = $payment->getCcNumber();
}
else
{
    $cc_num = $payment->getCcLast4();
    if (!empty($cc_num))
    {
        $cc_num = '************'.$payment->getCcLast4();
    }
}
$cc_year = sprintf('%02u%s', $payment->getCcExpMonth(), substr($payment->getCcExpYear(), 2)); 


    writeStartTag("Payment");
    writeElement("Method", Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($payment->getMethod())->getTitle());

    writeStartTag("CreditCard");
    writeElement("Type", $payment->getCcType());
    writeElement("Owner", $payment->getCcOwner());
    writeElement("Number", $cc_num);
    writeElement("Expires", $cc_year);
    writeCloseTag("CreditCard");

    writeCloseTag("Payment");

     writeStartTag("Notes");
    writeFullElement("Note", $payment->getPoNumber(),array("public" =>"true"));
   writeCloseTag("Notes");

    WriteOrderItems($order->getAllItems());

    WriteOrderTotals($order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shipworks is very picky about the XML tags that it receives.  You can't just add something to the response because it'll throw errors in the SW software when it tries to sync with your Magento store.  You can add it by using an existing element that isn't currently being used.  In our case, we weren't using Gift Messages, which get added to the response as *Notes*, so I re-purposed the *Notes* element to contain something else.

Look at the `WriteOrder` function (around line 396) and find this section:

```
if ($order->getGiftMessageId())
{
    $message = Mage::helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($order->getGiftMessageId());
    $messageString = "Gift message for ". $message['recipient']. ": ". $message['message'];

    writeStartTag("Notes");
    writeFullElement("Note", $messageString, array("public" => "true"));
    writeCloseTag("Notes");
}
```

Comment out this section and add something like this:

```
if ($order->getPoNumber())
{
    writeStartTag("Notes");
    writeFullElement("Note", $order->getPoNumber(), array("public" => "true"));
    writeCloseTag("Notes");
}
```

*NOTE: I don't know if `$order->getPoNumber()` actually works...this is just a sample of what you'll need to do*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I made the edits (I'm pretty sure that PoNumber is valid) & did a test order but nothing passed thru.  I'm going to test to see if the Gift Message passes through.  How about this section of the shipworks.php?    Does it need to be edited? 
 // Order-item level Gift Messages are created as item attributes in ShipWorks
 if ($item->getGiftMessageId())
      {
$message = Mage::helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($item->getGiftMessageId());

// write the gift message as an attribute
       writeStartTag("Attribute");
writeElement("Name", "Gift Message");

Comment: I had thrown that answer together based on changes I had made for a different result.  In your case, you're probably right.  The section in the "WriteOrderItems" function is probably where you want to add your changes.  I haven't tested it, so hopefully it'll work for you, but if not, post a followup and I'll see what I can do :)